# Session data displaying url of previous picture

Tags: php, session

I am trying to send data from one php file to another php file with sessions. Using ajax to refresh both scripts at same time on my main page.
One php script picks random picture from folder and displays it on main page, now I am trying to add report function that is in separated.

Now in file that is getting random picture I am doing

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['userName'] = 'Root';
$images[$i];
$_SESSION['picture'] = $images[$i];
```

and in my report.php I have

```
session_start();
$picturepath = $_SESSION['picture'];
echo $picturepath;
```

I am calling them like this in my mainfile.html

```
function Refresh()
{
$('#picturehere').load('getRandom.php')
$('#report').load('report.php')
};
```

Now the problem is, every time I execute that function, my report.php stores value from previous picture. But if I do <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f5</kbd>, the value will be from current picture.
Is there any way around this?

Example:
First refresh:

```
picture url: picture1.png
session value: picture1.png
```

Now calling Refresh function

```
picture url: picture2.png
session value: picture1.png
```

Comment: Set no-cache headers appropriately on the page you don't want the browser caching. Not doing so is the reason F5 gets the new version and the ajax request doesn't.

Comment: Tried it, found new problem, if you I get session, F5 doesn't work either.

Comment: $('#picturehere').load('getRandom.php?'+(new Date()).getTime());

Comment: Cache problem hard refresh required

Comment: I think it's because of parallel queries. what if you try to do it with callback?

$('#picturehere').load('getRandom.php', function(){$('#report').load('report.php');});

Comment: Thank you guys, num8er your solution is working indeed! Thanks a lot!