# Ajax calling multiple php files in same function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

So, few days ago I asked this question
[Session data displaying url of previous picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454114/session-data-displaying-url-of-previous-picture)

It is working, but is there any way to call multiple things at same time?

I have counter.php and report.php, they are both accessing session data from getRandom.php.

```
function Refresh()
{
$('#picturehere').load('getRandom.php', function(){$load('report.php');});
};
```

My Refresh() code.
I want to display counter.php in its own div, is this possible to do?

When I try to separate my counter.php in its own line like this its getting wrong session data, from previous picture.

```
function Refresh()
{
$('#picturehere').load('getRandom.php', function(){$load('report.php');});
$('#counter').load('counter.php');
};
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to make 3 different http requests / ajax calls to get information from the same server.

You should make one ajax call and combine the scripts on the server side or have one script that includes the other scripts. Then you can combine the output data in an array or object and `json_encode()` it to send it back to the browser. There you can get the different parts and put them in different html elements as desired.

You might need to move to a bit more complete method like [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) instead of just using `.load()` though.

Comment: Thanks, that summed it up. Got everything in 1 script and calling data as I need it. Working perfectly.