# Pass multiple parameters of one form to multiple php files using single jquery ajax method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, parameters

How to pass certain values of single html form to one file while some of its values to another file using single jquery ajax method?

Comment: using two ajax calls :)

Comment: You can call multiple PHP in one call check this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477072/ajax-calling-multiple-php-files-in-same-function

Comment: in most cases, except one, all other requests are redundant and useless.

Answer (score 0):

You could just include the second php file in the first by adding the below to the top of the first page:

```
include("secondPage.php");
```

Then, just make your ajax call to the first page. The second will also get the same values

Like this:

---

**firstPage.php :**

```
include("secondPage.php")

if( isset($_POST['myData']) ){
    // do stuff with $_POST['myData']
}
```

---

**secondPage.php :**

```
if( isset($_POST['myData']) ){
    // do more stuff with $_POST['myData']
}
```

---

**HTML page**

```
            var sendVars='myData=Cool Stuff';
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "firstPage.php",
                data: sendVars, 
                success: function(rtnData) {

                }
                });
             });
```

Comment: Thanks DelightedD0D.But can you please provide me syntax of the same in jquery ajax scenario?